# How to use Office 365 API in a VB 6.0 application

Tags: vb6, ms-office, office365

I am working on an application in VB 6.0. The application uses the MS Office API to interact with Office. Is it possible to use the Office 365 API in that application? If yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The Office 365 API is based on .NET, while VB 6 is not, you can use COM as a bridge: you write a C# DLL to access Office 365, then wrap it as COM component, then VB 6 can use the C# DLL via COM.

But I think this approach will be problematic. VB 6 is really too too old.