# Using Microsoft (Office) 365 tools in Visual Basic 6.0

Tags: excel, vb6, office365, activex, microsoft365

I'm developing an application written in Visual Basic 6.0 that supports exporting listViews to Microsoft Excel documents. Everything works perfectly fine if a user has an older version of Microsoft Office installed.

Now I want to add support for users who only have Microsoft/Office 365 on their systems. I've googled my way into depression in the past couple of days because I don't know much (or anything really) about dll/ocx files or registries. I'm not even sure if something like this can even be done because VB6 is really old, as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21301931/how-to-use-office-365-api-in-a-vb-6-0-application).

I've tried using [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?849821-How-to-make-all-versions-of-excel-work-in-Visual-Basic-6-pro&p=5187169&viewfull=1#post5187169) approach, but it didn't help me.

Right now, I'm getting a 429 runtime error

> ActiveX Component can't create object

on line

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

I only have Microsoft 365 trial version (no older ones) installed on the system and have these two things checked in my references:

[image]

I've also tried searching for `Excel.Application` in the registry, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/658846), but I can't find the path to the corresponding ActiveX file (which probably means it is not registered if I understand this correctly).

What can I do? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never mind, I found the answer myself. The problem was that I had older Office versions installed when I installed new 365 package and for some odd reason the .dll files for 365 version weren't registered. When I deleted those older versions all the working .dll files were gone with them.

I did a repair of the 365 installation and it's working perfectly now.